# Typescript: Dictionary type with keys which belongs to a nested type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

### Background

I am thinking if it's possible to create a type in TypeScript which allows to safely map the configuration with allowed values.

Given I have following interface which acts as a definition of some configuration node:

```js
interface CategoryDefinition {
    property1: string,
    actions: { [key: string]: string }
}
```

And the actual configuration that that implements that interface (which normally could be JSON loaded from file, the example is just to better illustrate the problem):

```js
const definitions: { [key: string]: CategoryDefinition } = {
    key1: {
        property1: "PROPERTY_NAME_1",
        actions: {
            action1: "ACTION_1",
            action2: "ACTION_2"
        }
    },
    key2: {
        property1: "PROPERTY_NAME_2",
        actions: {
            action3: "ACTION_3",
            action4: "ACTION_4"
        }
    },
    // etc...
};
```

The configuration is being mapped to objects having additional methods inside, so each `action` from `CategoryDefinition` has a `property1` from parent, like so:

```js
class ConfigValue {
    private propertyName: string;
    private action: string;


    constructor(category: string, action: string) {
        this.category = category;
        this.action = action;
    }

    methondOne(): void { /* doesn't really matter what's inside */}
}
```

### Problem

I want to keep such mapped objects in the config object / hashmap which has keys of `definitions` from previous example, and each object has keys from `Category.action` object nested inside.

```js
export const configMapped /*: TypeImLookingFor */ = {
    key1: {
        action1: ConfigValue("PROPERTY_NAME_1", "ACTION_1"),
        action2: ConfigValue("PROPERTY_NAME_1", "ACTION_2"),
    },
    key2: {
        action3: ConfigValue("PROPERTY_NAME_2", "ACTION_3"),
        action4: ConfigValue("PROPERTY_NAME_2", "ACTION_4"),
    },
}
```

**What type should I use to be sure that those `actions` belong to a finite valid set of keys that were defined in previous step?** My goal is to use this config in following way:

```js
// valid call, `action1` is valid key for `key1`
configMapped.key1.action1.methodOne();

// invalid call
configMapped.key1.action4;
```

Is it even possible in TypeScript? It doesn't have to be complex type, it can be set of different types related to each other.

Thanks for your help and opinion in advantage!

Comment: If it's JSON from a file you'll have a hard time because the [literal string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) property values will be widened to `string` which is useless for you; see [microsoft/TypeScript#32063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063).  Can you demonstrate how you will load the JSON?  I can probably make it work with `const definitions = { /*ur config here*/ } as const;` but there's no `as const` for importing JSON modules yet.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's JSON loaded from file, fetch from URL or an object as I wrote as an example - I can annotate it with proper type right after loading. And this isn't the real problem of the question I posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to get the behavior you want.  Here's how I'd write the mapping:

```
type MapConfig<T extends Record<keyof T, CategoryDefinition>> =
  { [K in keyof T]: { [P in keyof T[K]['actions']]: ConfigValue } };
```

And then, for a *sufficiently specific* `definitions`, you can write

```
type MappedDefinitions = MapConfig<typeof definitions>.
```

---

That could be the end of the answer, but there's a problem I was alluding to in the comments.  You *can't* do what you were doing here:

```
const badDefinitions:  { [key: string]: CategoryDefinition } = { /* config */ }
```

If you explicitly annotate the definitions variable as type `{ [key: string]: CategoryDefinition }`, then you have effectively thrown away any information the compiler could have about the specific keys and subkeys assigned to it.  The compiler says "okay, all I know about `badDefinitions` is that all its properties are `CategoryDefinition`s."

If you try to apply `MapConfig` to *that*, the lost information is still lost, and you get the most general type possible: an unspecified dictionary of unspecified dictionaries of `ConfigValue`s:

```
type BadMappedDefinitions = MapConfig<typeof badDefinitions>;
/* type BadMappedDefinitions = { [x: string]: { [x: string]: ConfigValue; }; } */
```

So you need to back up and have the compiler infer the type of `definitions`.  If you are doing it with the toy example in your question, this is no problem, just leave of the annotation:

```
const definitions = { /* same as yours */ }
```

or possibly use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) if you end up caring about the exact string values of the properties, (which you don't in this question but might in your real code):

```
const definitions = { /* same as yours */ } as const;
```

If you're importing from a static JSON file, you can do that with [`--resolveJsonModule`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule), but not with `as const` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#32063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063)
for the feature request for that).

If you're loading it via fetch after the code has been compiled, there's nothing you can do; the compiler is long gone by the time your JS runs and unless you know in advance the exact keys and properties that will come in you can't use a type annotation.  And if you do know that you might as well be using a static resource instead of fetching anything.

---

Assuming that this is just inline code and we let the compiler infer the type for `definitions`, then you can verify that `MappedDefinitions` evaluates to the desired type:

```
/*
type MappedDefinitions = {
    key1: {
        action1: ConfigValue;
        action2: ConfigValue;
    };
    key2: {
        action3: ConfigValue;
        action4: ConfigValue;
    };
}
*/
```

and use it,

```
const configMapped: MappedDefinitions = { /* same as yours */ };
```

giving you the type information needed to allow/disallow property accesses based on key name:

```
configMapped.key1.action1.methodOne(); // okay
configMapped.key1.action4; // error! action4 does not exist
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-tmIw4iIAfaxjPyaR8NoOJkB0-SbEMuyKOQqIL0nO0nwUPyvHlICJOUtjqQg8CtKyFwLESZIPN4DzyNwwofJKFQymom1KDKRNa0UkC2KNRpWg6bp+mGMZ9mtdYESuSZ7VBXKQFeAqisklTSt+CqAWq8ZJjqi5EWuOpmvER5MrwV4ctE3gOp47qyr+SrARqkFkHq7E+mRCajnBSgFMWsKpJ68r-iqoExuGhqcXGp4ppMBLhw88lSnJDVOHJGMXTjBMk3tSLiWQbBFDgPBYsS-t4PerLPsOkB0WBkkoBYKAAEJWvRHJc0KEBsAsKd3TAIA)

Comment: Wow, what an awesome answer! I'm extremely impressed :) And thanks for the addition, I knew I was doing something wrong before, that's why I put the "background" part with code examples to make the whole think more simple. I will try to remap that to my project and will let you know if it does the job :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: And sorry I misunderstood you in the comments before, I thought you were talking about totally different thing :)